# The server's publishing options in netbeans that like in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

The server's publishing options in Netbeans that like in Eclipse ?

Just like the feature in eclipse.

[image: Server's publishing options in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is like in Eclipse. But in Netbeans:

1. You will have to deploy the element yourself
2. Whenever you change a file (and save it) the resource will be deployed
3. Whenever you build, clean and build or something like that, the resource will be deployed.